# How to retrieve downloadable file size with curl command?

Tags: linux, shell-script, curl, size

I have a requirement in the shell script like, have to download a file from "url" with curl command. before downloading that file I want to process that same file size in a method.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `-I` option to only retrieve the headers, and look for the “Content-Length” header. Add the `-L` option if necessary to follow redirects. For example:

```
$ curl -L -I https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 09:51:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)
Location: https://gensho.ftp.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Expires: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 09:56:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 09:51:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 11:56:52 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 305135616
Age: 228
Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image
```

This shows that the file is 305,135,616 bytes in size.

You can filter this using Gawk for example:

```
$ curl -s -L -I https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso | gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^Content-Length/ { print $2 }'
305135616
```

(The `-s` option tells `curl` not to print progress information, which it does by default when its output is redirected.)

Note that this information isn’t always available so your script should be prepared to deal with that.

Comment: You can wrap it with `numfmt` to make it readable: `numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B $(curl -s -L -I https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"} /^Content-Length/ { print $2 }')`: `336MiB`

Comment: There seem to be some (legitimate) scenarios where the `Content-Length` header is missing. For example, if the protocol is `HTTP/1.1` and the response is and chunk encoded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375507/getting-response-of-http-request-without-content-length